# How to implement edit, update and discard functions in angular material table(mat-table)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to implement edit, update and discard functions in angular material table. I know how to edit and update table row wise but do not know how to discard the table rows.

please click on link [stackblitz link to table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-gwrmxy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) to see what i have done. if you know how to implement discard functions please help me, and any help would be appreciated, i do not how to keep the initial values of data cells. even i tried to keep a copy of the original data so that when they hit on discard button i can move copied data to particular row of the table. but because of 2 way data binding its directly updating to original data(i mean to company details array which is response from backend), i do not know how its reflecting and effecting original data. its a kinda weird thing i am facing here, please help me badly i need this answer thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wanna implement discard functionality properly we have a way, instead of following 2 way data binding we could follow reactive forms and could create form arrays. below is my solution.[table with discard functions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-tuffvv)

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the ngModel of the form fields to a temporary working copy. If the user then discards, you just need to remove the working copy and display the original contents again. If on the other hand the user wants to save, we Object.assign the changes to the table data.

See here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-njrnu9?file=app/app.component.ts

This solution is not perfect, but maybe it guides you in the right direction.

Comment: thx for the answer but its not correct. try to add one more row in table and now try to edit. this logic wont work.

Comment: Did not test every case. Was a suggestion on how you could handle the problem.

Comment: then you could have suggested me in comment section, anyways thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

when you edit make a copy of element. Then you has two aproach:

1.- you use [ngModel] with the copy and in update asign the value

2.- you use [ngModel] with the element and in cancel asign the copyvalue

To make a copy you need use the spread operator, to make a "copy", not to asign the same object to the two variables

```
this.oldValue={...element}
```

Well. You need choose if you can edit severals rows at time or only one. I think that it's more adecuate edit only one row at time (but it's only an opinion), so first, in stead of has in an array if a row is in edit mode or not you can use an unique variable `editIndex`

```
  editIndex:number=-1;
  editCompanyDetails(details,i) {
    this.editIndex=i;
  }
```

I choose edit the "copy", so I declare a variable `newValue`

```
  newValue:any;
  editCompanyDetails(details,i) {
    this.editIndex=i;
    this.newValue={...details}
  }
```

See how we make a copy using spread operator

There're a problem that we can not use the same mat-form field in edit mode and in read-only mode. MatTable not allow us make some like:

```
  <!-- this NOT WORK -->
  <input matInput placeholder="{{element.companyName}}"
             [(ngModel)]="editIndex==i?newValue.companyName:element.companyName"
             ...>
```

So, we need "repeat" the form field, one using element and one using newValue.

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="companyName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Company Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index">

          <!--this only show is editIndex!=i-->
          <mat-form-field *ngIf="editIndex!=i" floatLabel="never" [appearance]="'none'">
            <input matInput placeholder="{{element.companyName}}"
 [(ngModel)]="element.companyName"
         [readonly]="true">
         </mat-form-field>

          <!--this only show is editIndex==i-->
          <mat-form-field *ngIf="editIndex==i" floatLabel="never" [appearance]="'legacy'">
            <input matInput placeholder="{{element.companyName}}"
 [(ngModel)]="newValue.companyName"
         >
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Status </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index">

          <!--this only show is editIndex!=i-->
          <mat-form-field *ngIf="editIndex!=i" floatLabel="never" [appearance]="'none'">
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="element.status" [readonly]="true" >
          </mat-form-field>

          <!--this only show is editIndex==i-->
          <mat-form-field *ngIf="editIndex==i" floatLabel="never" [appearance]="'legacy'">
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="newValue.status"  >
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```

the functions update and cancel becomes like

```
  updateCompanyDetails(i){
    this.dataSourceCompanyDetails.data[i]={...this.newValue}
    this.editIndex=-1;
  }

  discardCompanyDetails(){
    this.editIndex=-1;
  }
```

You can see in this [forked stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-23dutm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: In this aproach, if you're editing one field and try edit another one, the changes are loose. Perhasf is time that, in edit function check if editIndex!=-1 to ask if you want to loose the changes (not in stackblitz)

```
  editCompanyDetails(details,i) {
    if (this.editIndex!=i && this.editIndex!=-1)
    {
       //get the element we are "editing"
       const data=dataSourceCompanyDetails.data[this.editIndex]
       if (data.status!=this.newValue.status || data.companyName!=this.newValue.companyName){
         ..ask if you want to loose the changes..
       }
    }
       if (this.newValue.
    this.editIndex=i;
    this.newValue={...details}
  }
```

**updated** y we take the another aproach declare a variable olValue and get the table using ViewChild -is necesary call to renderRows y cancel the edit.

```
@ViewChild('table') table:MatTable<any>
oldValue:any;
```

And change the functions as

```
  editCompanyDetails(details,i) {
    this.editIndex=i;
    this.oldValue={...details}
  }

  updateCompanyDetails(){
    this.editIndex=-1;
  }

  discardCompanyDetails(i){
    this.dataSourceCompanyDetails.data[i]={...this.oldValue}
    this.editIndex=-1;
    this.table.renderRows()
  }
```

Well, change the [NgModel]="newElement.company bt [ngModel="element.company". I'm in hurry, but this aproach you can use an unique formField, in the stackblitz I left the two formFields

See the [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-hyqvck?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: thx for the help, could you please make a new stackblitz. i tried but i am loosing data here when i click on edit. i do not want to loose data and it should work properly as expected, help me and thx.

Comment: @pk_teckie, if you don't want to loose data when you don't save, you need take the another aproach. make a copy and use the copy in cancel. I make another stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-hyqvck?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts -answer updated also-

Comment: thank you so much for the help, but as per your solution we cannot edit all the rows at time and one more thing here you could have suggested me the form array solution. anyways i got solution, but m not following 2 way data binding here. i have done through reactive forms, you could find it below. thanks once again, keep helping people and i appreciate help.

Comment: If you want to edit all rows at time, your'e correct. you need use an array of "oldValues". You can use your editAddCompanyDetailsTable[i] if you convert in an array of objects (with the sames properties than the dataSourceCompanyDetails.data + "onEditted" bool variable)