# Edit an input text in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular11

I have a form in `Angular` with an input type text that I need to be able to edit by hitting the edit button.

I have 3 buttons, `edit`, `cancel` the change and `save` the change.

If the edit button is pressed, the input is enabled to be able to modify it, the edit button is hidden and the save and cancel buttons are shown.

If the cancel button is pressed, the change is canceled and the text that was initially displayed is shown and only the edit button is shown.

If the save button is pressed, the current changes are saved and replaced by the previous information, and only the edit field is shown again.

This is my html with a single `input`:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10">
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
```

How can I get this behavior on the page? What functions should I add in `component.ts`?

Comment: Ever think about having a second hidden row with the edit fields, then hiding and showing the editing row in place of the display row?

Comment: @Chris Yes, I have also seen that it can be done but what I want is to be able to edit the fields within the same row, so that the cells are editable if I press a button and then accept or cancel the changes

Comment: @Merts, the only is to have in a cell a "span" with the value and a "input". see, e.g. this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64075553/how-to-implement-edit-update-and-discard-functions-in-angular-material-tablema/64077774#64077774 or this more beauty way to do it https://netbasal.com/keeping-it-simple-implementing-edit-in-place-in-angular-4fd92c4dfc70

Comment: @Eliseo By what I see they do not use a button, if not they edit the cell by clicking on it but well I can get something out of there the problem is to do the same but pressing a button

Comment: @mertz,  in the SO link use a button

Comment: @Eliseo If it is true I am now seeing the example of stackblitz, thank you I will pay attention to this, how could I hide the Update and Discard buttons and show them when the Edit button is pressed?

Comment: just us `<button *ngIf="editIndex!=i" ...>` and `<button *ngIf="editIndex==i" ...>`. The idea of the code is that a variable "editIndex" get the value of the "row" selected (or -1 if no row is selected).

Comment: @Eliseo I do not understand this much but okay I will try to see if I can show and hide

Comment: I forked the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-ydrfxm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html -see the `*ngIf` in buttons

Comment: @Eliseo Ok thanks with that it's ok, now I will adapt it to my table because my table is dynamic to be able to do the same in my component.ts

Comment: @Eliseo I can't adapt it to my code, in that example a table with data is defined and MatTableDataSource is used, but I'm not using that so I would have to edit it in another way

Comment: @Mertz, the idea is always the same (with a mat-data-table or not). You has a variable: "editIndex", and a variable "newObject". A button equal editIndex to the "row" selected and newObject to the values of the row. In .html the variable "editIndex" allow us show one button or another and a span or a input (or a input readonly and a input not read-only). The button "ok" is used to asign the values of the input to the table in the row selected

Comment: @Eliseo Yes, I have managed to change the buttons as you say, the problem I have when editing the cells that I do not know how to adapt it in my project. I don't know if using input would be easier? I'm struggling a lot and it doesn't seem difficult from what you say

Answer (score 0):

Have toedit = true in ur *.ts file

```
<div class="row g-0">
<div *ngIf="!toedit">
<label for=""> {{dataNew}} </label>
<div class="float-end">
<label><i class="fas fa-pencil p-1" (click)="toedit=!toedit"></i></label>
<label><i class="fas fa-minus-circle p-1" (click)="removeLabel(k)"></i></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="toedit">
<div class="col-10 align-self-center">
<input type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="col-1 ms-1 align-self-center">
<label><i class="fas fa-check" [(ngModal)] = "dataNew" (click)="updateLabel(dataNew)"></i></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Have a try on this